# What is the purpose of [key] in a C# object?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to code a WCF RIA class for the first time in C# (also my first time with the language), just to join some tables for a LightSwitch data source. Following the [example code](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/47/WCF-RIA-Service-Combining-Two-Tables.aspx), I created the following class to return my rows of data:

```
public class StudentTerm
{
    [Key]
    public string TermCode { get; set; }
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public decimal? TermGPA { get; set; }
    public decimal? CumulativeGPA { get; set; }
}
```

But I'm curious -- what is the purpose of the [Key] typedef? Does it apply only to *TermCode* in my example, or to the entire class?

Comment: That's your primary key - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Because you probably have a table `StudentTerm` in your database and `TermCode` is the primary key in table.

Comment: It's called an attribute and it only applies to `TermCode` in your example. I'm not familiar with the library to know what it represents.

Comment: @Darren So it's an attribute, setting TermCode as the key? Only `StudentID` would be unique, so I guess I need to edit the class.

Comment: `[Key]` is an attribute. Attributes only apply to the thing they're right before, so it's only on `TermCode`; if it were on the whole class it'd be `[Key] public class StudentTerm`

Comment: Yes, it's an attribute. It's likely you need to edit the class yes; especially if there are not DISTINCT `TermCode`. You will also likely need to change the `StudentID` type too - though don't know your business logic. If your table is going to contain a LOT of data then string as a PK will likely suffer performance.

Comment: And the way I see it, this is a transition table between Student and Term? You can define a composite key with the TermCode and StudentId properties by using the [Column(Order = 0), Key] attribute. Use Order = 0 for first part of key, and Order = 1 for second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Key` on top of `TermCode` is called [property attribute.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
Attributes provide a powerful method of associating declarative information with C# code (types, methods, properties, and so forth). Once associated with a program entity, the attribute can be queried at run time and used in any number of ways.
[More on attributes you can find here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208703/c-sharp-property-attributes)

In this speciffic case we are talking about WCF RIA Services attribute.
In WCF RIA Services each entity must have a primary key defined and you designate a property as the primary key with the [Key] attribute. You can decorate multiple properties if the class has a composite primary key.

Answer (score 2):

As @LIUFA says above, `Key` is an Attribute.  It's full name is `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute`  This is to denote that the Id field is the primary key of the underlying data store.

In a more general sense, an `Attribute` can decorate a class, method, property, or assembly.  They don't do anything on their own, but are used by other code to "mark" things.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check the msdn libraries for an answer:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And yes, it only applies to *TermCode*. Class attributes are placed just above the class definition.
Also *Key* Is a property of field attribute so it can't be applied to a class